# JavaScript: Loading <p> element with tags via xml DOM

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, tags

I am currently using JavaScript plus XMLHttpRequest to dynamically load some text into some portions of my website. In my .xml file, I am attempting to include some HTML tags like b, i, etc. as I want some of the text to be formatted. When I load the actual page, it's like the tags cut the string short.

**JavaScript**

```
    //Note: XML DOM is already loaded at this point...

    //Get the text from .xml doc
    var paragraph = xmlDOM.getElementsByTagName("Content")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("Paragraph").innerHTML = paragraph;
```

**Example.xml**

```
<Content>I am Some <b>Text</b></Content>
```

**Loads to page like this**

I am Some

Anyone know of a way to get around this like special escape characters that I can include in my .xml strings?

Comment: Not sure I get it, are you loading an XML file in the browser as a (X)HTML file, or just appending some content from XML into a HTML file or what ?

Comment: the .xml file contains some data that I want to display on my site. I first use Javascript to create an XML DOM object, then take the data from that object to populate content on the site. I can load a sentance for example with no issues, but I want some of that sentance to be formatted like normal HTML tags would do like bold, italic, etc.

Comment: @Shijima show us how you do it, we might be able to tell what's wrong in your code

Comment: Me thinks you can't do that, XML isn't HTML, and it's not displayed with the same styles

Comment: updated my original post, please let me know if more info is needed

Comment: you are only getting the first node which is the text node, use the following xmlDOM.getElementsByTagName("Content")[0].innerHTML

Comment: @T.V. innerHTML doesn't apply to xml DOM

Comment: @Christophe My mistake, I should have said the 'xml' property

Comment: @T.V. ok, I see. Unfortunately only few browsers support the xml property.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Turns out I needed to use escape characters in my .xml doc for the HTML tags.

**New Example.xml**

```
<Content>I am Some &lt;b&gt;Text&lt;/b&gt;</Content>
```

**This will now display as...**

I am Some **Text**